# Hide Order By Column From SELECT Without Using Temp Table

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by, distinct

Well, **I know we can hide order by column from select statement by using temp tables**. Just wondering **how to do the same without using temp tables**?

As the db I'm working is so huge, adding temp tables impact query performance a lot.

My Query is something like following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Col1,
  MAX(Col2),
  MAX(Col3),
  Col4
FROM 
  Table1
Group By
  Col4,
  Col1
Order By
  Col4
```

Now all i want is to get rid of Col4  from Output without using temp tables. Can't even do that using inner query. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If your **Col4** is computed/derived and it has to be in original select, you may simple make an `outer` query:

```
SELECT G.Col1, G.C2, G.C3 from
(SELECT DISTINCT
  Col1,
  MAX(Col2) AS C2,
  MAX(Col3) AS C3,
  Col4
FROM 
  Table1
Group By
  Col4,
  Col1
Order By
  Col4) AS G
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the sort column(s) does not need to be included in the select list. This is a common operation - no explicit temp table required.

```
select color
from fruit
order by weight
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba09d/3

Comment: Regarding the updated SQL, could the OP please give an sample scenario where this sort of query would be applicable.

(1) One should be advised that the DISTINCT alters the GROUP BY behavior in ways that are probably unpredictable. Small changes in data being aggregated could easily result in result rows appearing and disappearing.

(2) In my experience, DISTINCT almost always suggests some underlying design/code defect. Ymmv

(3) Why is the data being grouped by two columns, yet only one returned. Why not group on "Col1" only?

LMK if it would useful to have data demonstrating these points.